# Show/ Hide components on the selection of checkbox of a Tree

Tags: java, tree, zk

The onSelect event is present for the  component only and I want to show/hide my comboboxes for selected checkboxes only.

Here is my zul file for reference

```
![<?page title="MVVM Tree POC"?>
<zk>
    <borderlayout height="800px">
        <west size="25%"></west>
        <center>
            <window apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
                viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.nagarro.viewmodel.TreeViewModel')"
                title="Dynamic Tree" border="normal">
                <tree checkmark="true" model="@bind(vm.treeModel)"
                    onSelect="@command('select')">
                    <treecols>
                        <treecol label="Name" align="center" />
                        <treecol label="Value" align="center" />
                        <treecol label="IP" align="center" />
                    </treecols>
                    <template name="model" var="node" status="s">
                        <treeitem checkable="@load(node.checkable)">
                            <treerow style="text-align:center;">
                                <treecell
                                    label="@bind(node.data.firstName)" style="text-align:left;">

                                </treecell>
                                <treecell style="text-align:center;">
                                    <combobox>
                                        <comboitem label="Fixed" />
                                        <comboitem label="System" />
                                        <comboitem label="Parameter" />
                                    </combobox>
                                </treecell>
                                <treecell style="text-align:center;">
                                    <combobox>
                                        <comboitem label="IP" />
                                    </combobox>
                                </treecell>
                            </treerow>

                        </treeitem>
                    </template>
                </tree>

            </window>
        </center>
    </borderlayout>
</zk>]
```

[snapshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8E7n1.png)
In the image I want to show the combo boxes only for the components which have checked checkboxes. There should not be any combobox shown for component without checkbox or unchecked checkbox. Thanks

Here is the mvvm file

```
public class TreeViewModel {


    private Request request;
    private AdvancedTreeModel treeModel;

    /**
     * @return the treeModel
     */
    public AdvancedTreeModel getTreeModel() {
        if(treeModel == null){
            TreeNode<Tree> treeNode = new TreeList(request).getRoot();
            treeModel = new AdvancedTreeModel(treeNode);
            treeModel.setMultiple(true);
        }
        return treeModel;
    }

    /**
     * @param treeModel the TreeModel to set
     */
    public void setTreeModel(AdvancedTreeModel treeModel) {
        this.treeModel = treeModel;
    }
    @Init
    public void init(){
        try {
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\jatin1937\\Desktop\\XML files\\Request.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Request.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            request = (Request) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        }catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the request
     */
    public Request getRequest() {
        return request;
    }

    /**
     * @param request the request to set
     */
    public void setRequest(Request request) {
        this.request = request;
    }
    @Command
    public void select(){
        System.out.println("onSelect method entered");
    }
}
```

Tree data is prepared through some helper classes but thats not important to describe here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also tried it and found a way out. Now, instead of using `onSelect` event on `tree` component I am using `onClick` event on `treeRow` component.  I kept a field `isChecked` with my class which is referred by `node.data` in the zul file. According to the value of that boolean `isChecked` I show/hide the combobox.

Below is the zul file for reference

```
<?page title="MVVM Tree POC"?>
<zk>
    <borderlayout height="800px">
        <west size="25%"></west>
        <center>
            <window apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
                viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.nagarro.viewmodel.TreeViewModel')"
                title="Dynamic Tree" border="normal">
                <tree checkmark="true" model="@bind(vm.treeModel)">
                    <template name="model" var="node" status="s">
                        <treeitem
                            checkable="@load(node.data.isCheckable)" open="true">
                            <treerow style="text-align:center;"
                                onClick="@command('select', treeNode = node.data)">
                                <treecell
                                    label="@bind(node.data.firstName)" style="text-align:left;">
                                </treecell>
                                <treecell style="text-align:center;"
                                    if="${node.data.isChecked == true}">
                                    <combobox>
                                        <comboitem label="Fixed" />
                                        <comboitem label="System" />
                                        <comboitem label="Parameter" />
                                    </combobox>
                                </treecell>
                                <treecell style="text-align:center;"
                                    if="${node.data.isChecked == true}">
                                    <combobox>
                                        <comboitem label="Fixed" />
                                        <comboitem label="System" />
                                        <comboitem label="Parameter" />
                                    </combobox>
                                </treecell>
                            </treerow>
                        </treeitem>
                    </template>
                </tree>

            </window>
        </center>
    </borderlayout>
</zk>
```

Here is the `select` method in ViewModel for reference

```
@NotifyChange("treeModel")
@Command
public void select(@BindingParam("treeNode") final Tree tree){
    if(tree.getIsCheckable()){
        if(tree.getIsChecked() == true){
            tree.setIsChecked(false);
        }else{
            tree.setIsChecked(true);
        }
    }

}
```

> Please note that *Tree* is a custom class through which I prepare tree
>   data.  *isCheckable* is also a *boolean* field in the *Tree* class. If
>   *true* then *checkbox* will appear in a *treeRow* else not.
>   *isChecked* is another *Boolean* field in *Tree* class. If *true* then
>   corresponding *checkbox* is checked else not

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this

```
<tree onSelect="@command('select', tree=self)" >
```

and in your vm

```
Set<Treeitem> oldSelection;
...

@Command
public void select(@BindingParam("tree")Tree tree){
   // delete
   Set<Treeitem> unselected = oldSelected.removeAll(tree.getSelectedItems());
   for(Treeitem x : unselected){
       x.getTreerow().getLastChild().setParent(null);
   }
   // add
   tree.getSelectedItem().getTreerow().appendChild(getCombobox());
   oldSelection = tree.getSelectedItems()
}
```